# how to create a stored procedure to get opening balance from database to a date range crystal report

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports

I have a database with debit and credit column. I've created a crystal report from this database as a date range report and a new column added using formulas for balance. Now I need a row to get the previous day balance from database to my report.For this option i need to create a custom stored procedure. Can anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: it seems a little strange (or excess) to create SP for this... can you explain this point a little bit more, please?

Answer (score 0):

In general I suggest you not to use Crystal for extending the data you have in the database (adding columns, formulas, etc). Crystal scripts (for my experience) is cumbersome, unobvious and hardly-maintainable. Thereby I suggest you wherever it possible to use SQL - create and extend data-model through views and use these views as data-source for Crystal reports.

As for your specific case, if for example you have the table with columns `debit` and `credit` and you need to extend your data with additional column `balance` and `previous_balance`, the solution might look something like this:

```
create table your_table (id int, [day] date, credit float, debit float);

insert into your_table (id, [day], credit, debit) values
(1, '2014-12-04', 0.0, 340.00),
(2, '2014-12-05', 10000.0, 0.00),
(3, '2014-12-06', 7666.18, 89.00),
(4, '2014-12-07', 0.0, 990.00);

-- create view dbo.your_table_extension as
select t1.[day]
, t1.credit
, t1.debit
, t1.credit - t1.debit [balance]            --> balance formula
, t2.credit - t2.debit [previous_balance]   --> prev day balance formula
from your_table t1
left join your_table t2 on dateadd(day, -1, t1.[day]) = t2.[day]
  and t1.id != t2.id
```

Result:

```
DAY         CREDIT  DEBIT   BALANCE PREVIOUS_BALANCE
----------------------------------------------------
2014-12-04  0       340     -340    (null)
2014-12-05  10000   0       10000   -340
2014-12-06  7666.18 89      7577.18 10000
2014-12-07  0       990     -990    7577.18
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/878dc/1)

Comment: As you showed in the result, i need to store previous balance line on first row of the report and Brought forward balance. I tried with formulas its not working. I need only three columns as shown in the result credit, debit and Balance column. If i filter the above result from 2014-12-05 the first row wants to show -340.00. It's like a bank statement

Comment: but how the FIRST row of the report can store PREVIOUS balance? There nothing could be before the first row... anyway I can't figure out your problem